# Wordpress Permanlink 404

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, http-status-code-404

My new server. AX101 of hetzner dedicated server. Have try with NGINX and Apache.

I was migrate wordpress from hotarmada/godaddy to new server.

Migration was no problem, but I was facing 404 on blogs when enable Strip Category Base with Rank Math plugin.

Please advice how do I resolve it.

I have switch within NGINX and Apache with htacees.

https://wwww.123.com/category/blogs/ , this no problem.

when enable strip category,
https://www.123.com/blogs/. , 404

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.